# C++ Multiple Inheritance to Implement Polymorphism

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

In the **[JSF C++ Coding Standards](http://www.stroustrup.com/JSF-AV-rules.pdf)**, AV Rule 87 shows a diagram of abstract base class and an implementation as multiple inheritance.

1. What is this diagram trying to show?
2. In this example, What is the purpose of the Private/Protect inheritance?
3. How does does one create an implementation as a base class?
4. The Diagram from AV Rule 87 shows that D1 is inheriting from an impl; Is this impl a different implementation that has nothing to do with interface?

> **AV Rule 87**
>
> Hierarchies should be based on abstract classes. See Stroustrup 2,
>   12.5.
>
> ***Rationale:*** 
>        Hierarchies based on abstract classes tend to focus designs toward producing clean interfaces, keep implementation details out of
>   interfaces, and minimize compilation dependencies while allowing
>   alternative implementations to coexist. See AV Rule 87 in Appendix A
>   for examples.
>
> ...
>
> **Appendix A - AV Rule 87**
>
> Hierarchies based on abstract classes are preferred. Therefore the
>   hierarchies at the top of the diagram are preferred over the hierarchy
>   at the bottom of the diagram.
>   [image: JSF AV Rule 87]

Using the classic polymorphism example of shapes:

[image: Classic Shapes Polymorphism example]

5.
Would my implementation be the following? This doesn't seem correct to me. I fear, I am missing the purpose of the design. Traditionally I would expect Right_Triangle to inherit from Triangle.

```
 class Shape{};                              // Interface
 class Right_Triangle{};                     // Impl    
 class Triangle : public Shape,
                  private Right_Triangle {}; // D1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is mostly correct, and adheres to the spirit of AV 87. You've made a typo though, the implementation and the public class should be of the same "kind" (so, both should be a generic triangle, for example):

```
class IShape { ... };      
class TriangleImpl { ... }; 
class Triangle : public IShape,
                 private TriangleImpl { ... };
```

The diagram that purports that a right triangle *is a* triangle is **wrong**, and a common misconception. A right triangle isn't a triangle, unless you explicitly limit what you can do with a triangle (e.g. make it read only). A triangle can have whatever edge lengths you desire. A class inheriting from a triangle must still *act like a triangle would. It's known as the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Since you  **can't** use a `RightTriangle` class everywhere a `Triangle` class can be used without limitations that make `Triangle` useless as a concrete class (you can't set edge lengths on a triangle) - thus the inheritance hierarchy as shown is just bad design.

The *design of a class hierarchy* doesn't necessarily follow a Venn diagram, nor should it follow "everyday truths". Long software engineering practice shows that sane inheritance diagrams are obtained when you stick to LSP.

Yes, the textbooks that demonstrate this "right triangle is a triangle" insanity **are wrong** if they don't offer a concrete design that satisfies LSP. In the case of shapes, the `Trilateral` and `Quadrilateral` interfaces must be read only, and the specific vertex- or edge-setting methods can only be offered in the derived classes, since they adhere to different limitations. The derived concrete classes need a flat hierarchy (a `Square` isn't a `Rectangle` - if it were, you could set two different edge lengths for it!). Similarly, as far as LSP goes, a `Square` isn't a `Quadrilateral`, since quadrilaterals can have arbitrarily placed vertices, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand 'the spirit' of AV 87. I still don't understand the benefits (or cons) of inheriting from your implementation. Could you elaborate further?

Comment: @Jerunh The implementation class is forced, by design, to do only one thing or one aspect of the job, an aspect that has to be self-contained by design. The `Triangle` class would contain probably some trivial adapters between `IShape` and `TriangleImpl`. It makes it much easier to swap implementations.

Comment: @KubaOber: even though I used the "Right Triangle is a Triangle" statement in my answer, I agree with your answer.  Maybe that is a downfall of OO in that objects representing reality is really difficult.  Context (problem domain) is key here: if the objects represent drawings, then the statement "Right Triangle is a Triangle" may be true (albeit useless, right triangle should be an instance), but for geometrical entities, you are right.  BTW: animal hierarchies are even worse.

Answer (score 2):

A Right Triangle is a Triangle, so the inheritance is the other way around.

In your example, Shape must be an abstract class according to the coding rule.  So shape can only declare pure virtual functions like Print(), Load(), rotate(),...

To inherit from another implementation (next to the shape hierarchy), public inheritance shouldn't be used.

Comment: Could you further explain what you mean to inherit from another implementation? What would an example of this be?

Comment: Other implementations may become a bit surreal for this example, but say that you want your triangle to play a sound, then it could inherit from a sound making class, then it shouldn't use public inheritance, but provide it own functions to access the sound playing implementation.